# how is dummy variable model different from a normal regression model?

Tags: regression

What are the differences between a normal regression model and a model with dummy variable?  When do i use which? 
Is regression the same as ANOVA? or ANOVA is a type of regression?

Comment: What do you mean here by "a normal regression model"?

Answer (score 1):

Jacob Cohen an NYU statistician wrote some seminal books and papers in the 60s treating ANOVA models as a subset of multiple regression. To the best of my knowledge, his views prevail today. What's changed in the decades since is the explosion of possible functional forms which that "regression" model can take.

I will admit that I'm not sure what a "normal" regression model is. There are plenty of examples of *textbook* regression models which are typically based on one or two continuously distributed predictors and a single dependent or response variable. In this context, "normal" is provisional since there are so many potential models that can be fit, even with problems this small.

For the purposes of argument let's assume a simple OLS multiple regression with two predictors *X1* and *X2*, a single predictor *Y* and no interaction or higher order polynomial terms. This is a *main effects* only model. If the *Xs* are continuously distributed, then the coefficients resulting from the OLS estimation represent the average change in *Y* for each unit change in, first, *X1* at all possible values of *X2*. The reverse is also true for *X2*.

Dummy variables are used when information is *not* continuously scaled but is more qualitative or categorical in nature. Examples of this include gender, religion, the teams comprising the NFL, and so on. The only rules are that the categories do not overlap or are mutually exclusive and span all of the possible values of the space occupied by that qualitative variable.

So, one can easily imagine a regression model predicting, e.g., income, in which, holding everything else constant, female employees are found to systematically make less money than male employees. This can have multiple causes but, clearly, sex influences earning power and, therefore, belongs in a predictive model of income.

The parameter estimate for gender in this model are an adjustment to the intercept of the model when gender is equal to "1" as a function of whether "1" has been assigned to male or female.

The situation becomes only slightly more complicated when the categories in a qualitative predictor are greater than two, e.g., there are *k* levels or categories. One's options, in this case, are many but basically boil down to two: the most typical choice is to assign a *reference* level from among the *k* categories which is to be set to zero, include an intercept, *a*, in the model and estimate. There will be a parameter for each of the k-1 nonreference levels and the *kth* or reference level will be zero. Each *k-1* parameter is then an estimate of the difference at that level for the change in *Y* relative to the reference or zero level.

A second, less frequently used, approach is to drop the intercept, *a*, and estimate the model using all *k* levels simultaneously. This would facilitate an interpretation of the resulting parameters as the direct impact on *Y* when that *kth* level is true or "1."

What is your data like? Can you now envision when you would use dummy variables vs not?

Comment: i dont really have a set of datas for comparison but just unsure and confused with the concepts of the models. Like if i were given a case or question and are required to choose the most suitable model i would confuse with which one to use. is dummy variable actually different regressors that are added to the regression?

Comment: Yes. Dummy variables are separate predictors in a model, when used as appropriate.